# Class properties - dot or equal sign

Tags: typescript

I'm reading angular docs and all classes have properties defined like:

```
class A {
a = 2;
};
```

and in the typescript official docs:

```
class A {
a:2
}
```

why is that and which one is right?

Comment: What docs show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **=** sign will generate a class member with the value **2**. The **:** seems be generating a property with the type **2** but it's value is actually undefined.

You can see it easily in the transpiled code.

This code:

```js
class A {
  x: 2;
  y = 2;

  method() {
    console.log(this.x)
  }
}

console.log(new A().x)
```

Transpiles to:

```js
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.y = 2;
    }
    A.prototype.method = function () {
        console.log(this.x);
    };
    return A;
}());
console.log(new A().x);
```

You can see it working in the playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20y%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%7D#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20y%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20method()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.x)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20A().x)).